# Vertical navigation with fluid horizontal sub menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I'd like to build a vertical navigation. It's a bit special because the **sub navigation should be displayed right next to the main links and should be fluid** like this:

```
 Item 1 
 Item 2 | Subitem 1 | Subitem 2 | Subitem 3
 Subitem 4 | Subitem 5 | Subitem 6
 Item 3
 Item 4   Subitem 1 | Subitem 2 
 Item 5
```

I'm looking for a solution to make the sub menu fluid, so that the **elements stays in the main menu row and breaks dynamically**. How to break the sub list items like in the example above?

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/11/

```
ul > li > a {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

ul > li:hover > .sub-menu{
    display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.sub-menu li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.sub-menu li:first-child{
    border-left: 2px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm looking for a solution to make the sub menu fluid, so that it stays in the main menu row and breaks dynamically - maybe my example was not correct. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/12/) - for better understanding the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It just looks like you added additional .sub-menu li's.

Comment: I got it, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/14/). `float:left` attribute of `sub-menu` causes the line break. Without it's fluid and on the same row like the main menu item. Feel free to edit your question, I will accept your edit. Thanks again.

Comment: No, I don't see the line break you're referring to. I'm on a 1920x1080 monitor though....if I shrink the browser I see the nav items wrap, but i don't see a line break.

Comment: Yours (with linebreak): http://i.stack.imgur.com/rCIp0.png, Mine (without): http://i.stack.imgur.com/OLeVf.png. Hope that's useful.